# Redhat route InfiniBand problem

Tags: linux, rhel, route

I have a system (HPC) have

- 1 headnode (192.168.2.2)
- 10 node and (192.168.245-254)
- 1 NFS server (192.168.2.244).

My headnode can't ping to NFS server but from NFS server I can ping to headnode.

I already disable firewall in 2 PC but it still didn't work.

**HeadNode**
route -n (192.168.2.2)

```
[root@cluster ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.39.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ib0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
172.16.112.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
10.10.41.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em2
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 pem3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1006   0        0 ib0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1030   0        0 em1
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 pem3
```

arp -a

```
[root@cluster ~]# arp -a
compute-0-5.local (192.168.2.249) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (10.10.41.1) at <incomplete> on em2
compute-0-0.local (192.168.2.254) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
compute-0-3.local (192.168.2.251) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
compute-0-4.local (192.168.2.250) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
compute-0-7.local (192.168.2.247) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (10.10.10.218) at f8:28:19:1f:22:33 [ether] on pem3
? (10.10.11.17) at 88:e9:fe:70:25:26 [ether] on pem3
compute-0-6.local (192.168.2.248) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
compute-0-1.local (192.168.2.253) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (10.10.10.47) at c0:cb:38:3e:72:6d [ether] on pem3
? (10.10.10.1) at 1c:df:0f:b7:11:3f [ether] on pem3
compute-0-2.local (192.168.2.252) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
rockscluster-nfs (192.168.2.244) at <incomplete> on ib0
```

It can't connect to IP 192.168.2.244

NFS server

route -n

```
[root@rockscluster-nfs ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.40.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 em1
10.10.40.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 em1
10.10.41.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 em1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     150    0        0 ib0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

arp -a

```
[root@rockscluster-nfs ~]# arp -a
? (192.168.2.250) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
gateway (10.10.40.1) at <incomplete> on em1
? (192.168.2.253) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (192.168.2.248) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (10.10.41.149) at <incomplete> on em1
? (192.168.2.251) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (10.10.41.223) at a0:48:1c:df:f8:86 [ether] on em1
? (10.10.41.119) at 80:18:44:e6:48:9d [ether] on em1
? (10.10.41.1) at <incomplete> on em1
? (192.168.2.254) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (10.10.11.209) at d8:9e:f3:18:39:26 [ether] on em1
? (192.168.2.249) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (192.168.2.252) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (192.168.2.247) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
? (192.168.2.2) at 48:00:00:80:fe:80:00:00:00 [infiniband] on ib0
```

Comment: I can see two network cards using the same IP LAN (ib0 and em1 on same 192.168.2.0/24). That's usually not done, because this can cause "arp flux" issues at best, or worse (if the cards aren't actually seing each others). Also, when a question is put on hold, that's to ask you yo clarify it. This question is probably related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490923/rock-cluster-child-node-cant-ping-to-cluster-node , so answerers can get a better picture.